# Duplicate and rename a sheet (only it`s data) at fixed hr and day

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

every monday I've to make a copy of a sheet which is called week_nn, where nn is a progressive number of the current week for that sheet from its beginning. At some point of the day, we have to fix those data to make a history, and so I duplicate the sheet which take the standard name of "copy_of_week_nn_WIP" to "copy_of_week_nn_FRZ". If possible, I'd like to automathize this with a triggered script (time/day, in this case, every monday), because sometimes it happened if forgot the task and also, because it`s a stupid job...how I could possible do it?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hmm not exactly I think...but should be in someway adaptable I guess...maybe with a trigger, I'll look into it, thx

Comment: @SimoneRosmarino Hi and welcome. Your comment in response to Ruben is a little  confusing. We're not trying to fob you off, we just want to know what you have considered so that we don't reinvent the wheel and also get an idea of your skills.  Regarding a trigger, I agree about a [Time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).